# Cannot get the right nuget version for SQLite for Xamarin

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I am using a .NET Standard 2.0 project and can not add the Nuget package Sqlite.Net-PCL.
I want to be able to perform asynchronous database CRUD methods.
The popup message says it is trying to restore using the .Net Framework 4.6 rather than the target framework .Net Standard 2.0.

[image]

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you not better off using [SQLite.net.pcl (Frank Krueger)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl) rather than [SQLite.net-PCL (OysteinKrog)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/)?

SQLite.net-PCL isn't being maintained anymore see the top of the README [here](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL). The OysteinKrog version was a fork of the Frank Krueger (Original) version, I think due to it not being actively developed years ago but now Frank and others are actively maintaining the project. I would suggest switching to it.

[SQLite.net.pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl) supports .NET standard, see the release 1.3.0 [here](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/releases/tag/v1.3.0)

In saying that the warning you are seeing is just letting you know that it has targeted the .NET Framework v4.6.1 version of the NuGet package rather than finding a .NET Standard version. This means it has found a version but the NuGet Package doesn't officially support .NET Standard 2.0 so it could still work but is not tested.

Comment: Yes I should have chosen the Frank Krueger package

Comment: No worries, it's a very subtle change in the name, I have added the wrong one many times by accident.

Comment: both ther version of SQLite are older and could not find any other good nuget package, why there is not official nuget package from Microsoft/Xamarin/SQLite ? Which current version or nuget should i use ?

Comment: I would use the latest here https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl As to the why isn't there a Microsoft/Xamarin/SQLite I have no idea.